# Random Products magento showing 2 fixed products everytime

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento's default random product block. As it was working fine before today. but now it is showing only two fixed products every time. I have set a limit of 5 Products.

Suddenly, It is behaving strange.

This is the code I have in Random block

```
  protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $collection->addStoreFilter();
            $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 0;
            $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

and this is the block code I have in Home CMS page.

> {{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="product_random"
>   num_products="5" template="catalog/product/random.phtml"}}

and this is my call in template file.

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

One more annoying thing is if I set a product to be new in admin site that is showing in the random product list.
What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps! That was a re-index issue again!!!.

After reindexing, Random products block works as expected.

What's happening, Magento only picking up random products from newly created/updated products.

Just a guess of reindexing in the evening made my night.